# How to implement google analytics on vue app on multiple domains?

Tags: google-analytics, vuejs2, multiple-domains

I have multiple domains that use the same files (from git master branch). Now, I want to implement google analytics on each domain.

I've tried this vue-anlaytics package multiple domain tracking (see link - https://medium.com/dailyjs/tips-tricks-for-vue-analytics-87a9d2838915#7ead) but the problem is whenever I try to visit domain1.com. It also registers on the domain2.com google analytics dashboard.

Please help.

Comment: How do you have GA implemented currently? The link you sent is for tracking on multiple properties. So it is doing what it is supposed to do. I would like to know about how you have GA coded so we can come to a solution together.

Comment: Hi, you're right. And I misunderstood how it was supposed to do. My bad though. I ended up defining the ga_id as an environment variable on each domain and injected the ga_id from there. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining the tracking code or GA_ID to an environment variable on each instance helped me solve the issue.